# smarty var default value, escape curly braces

Tags: php, javascript, json, smarty, smarty3

i am having difficulty setting a default var value in smarty to have curly braces contained in it, i'm trying to do the following with no luck.

```
<input type="hidden" id="orders" value="{$orders|default:'{}'}">
```

also tried ldelim and rdelim with no luck either.

```
<input type="hidden" id="orders" value="{$orders|default:'{ldelim}{rdelim}'}">
```

is there some basic smarty syntax that im missing or will i have to devise a work around solution?

Answer (score 2):

To escape braces in Smarty, surround them with any ***whitespace characters***, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="orders" value="{$orders|default:' { } '}">
```

You can also escape CSS or JavaScript sections with the **{literal}** tags:

```
<input type="hidden" id="orders" value="{$orders|default:'{literal}{}{/literal}'}">
```

Comment: Both braces must have whitespace around it (space or newline).

Comment: both methods don't work, I've tried the literal method before as well

Comment: Fatal error: Smarty error: syntax error: unrecognized tag: $orders|default:' { (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 446) in

Answer (score 2):

You cannot inside tag inside tag. The only way to add default value here is to use condition:

```
<input type="hidden" id="orders" value="{if $orders}{$order}{else}{ldelim}{rdelim}{/if}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes

```
<input type="hidden" id="orders" value="{$orders|default:"{ldelim}{rdelim}"}">
```